# Why are my polar grid lines limited by the maximum radial value?

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I am wondering why the displayed polar grid lines are limited by the maximum plotted value (see minimal example below) - is it possible to show polar grid lines beyond the largest radial value?

Thanks and Best,
Tim

```
{ListPolarPlot[{{\[Pi]/4, 0.5}}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/24], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}],
 ListPolarPlot[{{\[Pi]/4, 0.8}}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/24], 
    Range[0, 1, 0.1]}]}
```

Comment: a work-around: add a second data set with invisible styling: `{ListPolarPlot[{{{\[Pi]/4, 0.5}}, Style[{{0, 1}}, Opacity[0]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/24], 
    Range[0, 1, 0.1]}], 
 ListPolarPlot[{{{\[Pi]/4, 0.8}}, Style[{{0, 1}}, Opacity[0]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/24], 
    Range[0, 1, 0.1]}]}`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I've done for now - but still a bit disappointing that this seems to be the only possible work-around